# PHP: Infer return type of this method chain

Tags: php

I am using PHPStorm.
As an example, I have a simple query class with all sorts of methods to take care of sorting, filtering, ect. It eventually returns an instance of the class passed in the constructor.

```
class AnimalQuery {
    private $classString;

    public function __construct(string $classString){
        $this->classString = $classString;
    }

    public function where(string $key, string $val): AnimalQuery {
        // Database things would happen here
        return $this;
    }

    public function orderBy(string $val): AnimalQuery {
        // Database things would happen here
        return $this;
    }

    public function first() {
        // Database things would happen here
        return new $this->classString();
    }
}
```

And a class that acts as a model, for example:

```
class Dog {
    public static function query(): AnimalQuery {
        return new AnimalQuery(static::class);
    }

    public function bark() {
        echo 'Woof!';
    }
}
```

It can be called like so:

```
$doggo = Dog::query()->where('name', 'Fido')->orderBy('species')->first();
$doggo->bark();
```

This does return an instance of Dog. However, PHPStorm of course does not understand that. Is there a way to clue PHPStorm in that the first method returns an instance of the class passed in the constructor of AnimalQuery?

In Typescript I might've used generics for this, but those do not exist in PHP.

Comment: As `first()` technically returns anything at the moment, how would PHPStorm know?  At the very least you could make `first()` return an `Animal` base class and inherit `Dog` from that.  However, as you've said, without generics there's no way for PHPStorm to know it's a `Dog` specifically.

Comment: The crappy workaround I use all the time in cases like this is comment-based typehinting...
```
$doggo = Dog::query()->where('name', 'Fido')->orderBy('species')->first(); /* @var $doggo Dog */
$doggo->bark();
```